# Order of Infinitesimal of $1-\cos \alpha$ relative to $\alpha$

Tags: analysis, limits, infinitesimals

### Exercise

> Let the central angle $\alpha$ of a circle of sector $ABO$ with radius $R$ tend to zero. Determine the order of the infinitesimal relative to the infinitesimal $\alpha$ of the line $CD$.
>   [image: 1]

---

### Attempt

*As I was typing up my attempt, I had a revelation, and solved the whole thing! I've decided to put my solution as and answer down below.*

---

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

$DC(\alpha) = R(1 - \cos \alpha)$

I must find $n$ such that $\lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos \alpha}{\alpha^n}} \neq 0$.

$\lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos \alpha}{\alpha^n}}$
$= \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos \alpha}{\alpha^n}\frac{1+\cos \alpha}{1+\cos \alpha}}$
$= \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos^2 \alpha}{\alpha^n(1+\cos \alpha)}}$
$= \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{\alpha^n(1+\cos \alpha)}}$
$= \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1}{\alpha^{n-2}(1+\cos \alpha)}}$

If $n = 2$, then $\alpha^{n-2}=1$, so
$\lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1}{\alpha^{n-2}(1+\cos \alpha)}}$
$= \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}{\frac{1}{1+\cos \alpha}}$
$= \frac{1}{1+\cos 0}$
$ = \frac{1}{2}$

---

### Answer

$$n = 2$$

The order of the infinitesimal $1-\cos \alpha$ relative to the infinitesimal $\alpha$ is $2$.